# How can I trigger a link when using jQuery TreeView Plugin?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, treeview

I have a JSP page that creates a treeview using jQuery treeview plugin. Now I want to make the single files selectable, that means I want to open a url when a file is clicked. I tried several example but non of them worked. This is an example html page:

```
<ul id="browser" class="filetree">
    <li><span class="folder">Folder 1</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="file">Item 1.1</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span class="folder">Folder 2</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="folder">Subfolder 2.1</span>
                <ul id="folder21">
                    <li><span class="file">File 2.1.1</span></li>
                    <li><span class="file">File 2.1.2</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span class="file">File 2.2</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="closed"><span class="folder">Folder 3 (closed at start)</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="file">File 3.1</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span class="file">File 4</span></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#browser").treeview({
            toggle: function() {
                console.log("%s was toggled.", $(this).find(">span").text());
                alert("do something");
            }
        });

        // fourth example
        $("#black, #gray").treeview({
            control: "#treecontrol",
            persist: "cookie",
            //cookieId: "treeview-black"
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: Hiya @dooonot so you mean click another url when you click say Item 1.1? just checking before I set my reply :) Have a nice one, cheers!

Comment: Hi Tats_innin, I want to open let's say test.html when I click on Item 1.1. But I want to control it with JavaScript. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: copy that - @doonot so you want to forward to the url from Jquery code not through predefined URL link bruv? cheers

Comment: Yes. Every item has an ID and I want to transmit this ID if somehow possible. Then if I click on the item, I want to show the detail information in a different <div>. I think that should be possible somehow?

Comment: Saweet, thanks; yep wait I am tweaking my solution for that in a bit, ! cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiya **demo** here : ) http://jsfiddle.net/yeMy9/1/  **&&** http://jsfiddle.net/yeMy9/2/ (only triggers when you click items not the folders. or  http://jsfiddle.net/yeMy9/3/

Now I have put the alert when you click the items inside the folder like Item 1.1 etc... and you can use conditional statement to decide base on where to fwd it.

Cheers and I am sure this will helps!

**Jquery Code**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#browser").treeview({
            toggle: function() {
                console.log("%s was toggled.", $(this).find(">span").text());
                alert("do something");

            }
        });

      $("li span").click(function(){
          alert(' Forward the url when clicked => ' + $(this).text());
          //Now forward to the link according to the text() i.e. based
          // on Item 1.1 & 2.2 etc...
      });

        // fourth example
        $("#black, #gray").treeview({
            control: "#treecontrol",
            persist: "cookie",
            //cookieId: "treeview-black"
        });
    });​
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="browser" class="filetree">
    <li><span class="folder">Folder 1</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="file">Item 1.1</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span class="folder">Folder 2</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="folder">Subfolder 2.1</span>
                <ul id="folder21">
                    <li><span class="file">File 2.1.1</span></li>
                    <li><span class="file">File 2.1.2</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span class="file">File 2.2</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="closed"><span class="folder">Folder 3 (closed at start)</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="file">File 3.1</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span class="file">File 4</span></li>
</ul>​
```

Comment: This is very nice, thanks man. But now it alerts me for every click. (also when I click on a folder). Can I have it only when I click on "files"?

Comment: @dooonot no worries man! Glad it helped bruv :)) yeah you can have specific tag or class for file items and the use it like $("li.itemclass).text() let me see if **I can make something for you :) and don't forget to accept the answer**, cheerios !

Comment: @dooonot Here you go man : http://jsfiddle.net/yeMy9/2/ and do not forget to accept the answer :)) have a good one bruv, cheers!

Comment: I have one more for you, is it possible to transmit a hidden ID rather than just getting the text? This would save a lot of work.

Comment: @dooonot okies yep it is possible will give you a sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/yeMy9/3/  **Now click on that +1 up arrow in the answer above in post** lolz, hope this helps! (In alert you will get the id popping up)